# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest doesn't work with api key

Tags: powershell, api

I want to call an api and I can't because of the api key type authorization.

I leave you an example of how I call it via postman and it works for me:

[image: Screenshot of successful request in Postman]

This is the code that I have that doesn't work for me:

```
<code>
$headers = @{Authorization="auth_token codeKeyhere"}
$params = @{
    Uri         = 'endopointhere'
    Method      = 'GET'
    ContentType = 'application/json'
}

$response =  Invoke-RestMethod @params -Header $header
$response
</code>
```

Comment: Try following : $headers = @{Authorization='auth_token codeKeyhere', ContentType = 'application/json'}
$response =  Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Get' -Uri  'endopointhere' -Header $header

Comment: How do you know the API key is the issue? Are there any (error) messages? (Please add more details [**to the question**](javascript:void(0)) why you suspect the API key)

Comment: Invoke-RestMethod : Error en el servidor remoto: (401) No autorizado.



It is not a problem with the api, if I consult it through postman it returns information.

Comment: It is not a basic authentication, it is of type "API key" at least that's how it works for me in postman

Comment: Change `$headers = @{Authorization="auth_token codeKeyhere"}` to `$headers = @{auth_token="codeKeyhere"}`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen , I change it and it gave me the following error: Remote server error: (406) Not acceptable.